# jQuery fullcalendar doesn't update database after resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, save, fullcalendar

Ola,

I got some events stored in a database and i'm showing these in my jquery fullcalendar. Now i also got it working so that i can change the day of an event by draging and dropping. Changing the time by resizing a event i can't get working tho.

I guess it has something to do with me not giving a time here:

```
start = moment(start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
end = moment(end, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But all the formats i tried (for instance: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss)  give this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
```

Now with my current code i **can** resize elements, it only doesn't save them in my database. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "http://localhost/plann/events.php",
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');

            if (title) {
                start = moment(start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                end = moment(end, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/plann/add_events.php',
                    data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end ,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(json) {
                        alert('OK');
                    }
                });

                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            start = moment(event.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            end = moment(event.end, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/plann/update_events.php',
                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });
        },

        eventResize: function(event) {
            start = moment(event.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            end = moment(event.end, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/plann/update_events.php',
                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });  
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: you know that `start` and `end` are already moments, right? That applies to the resize, drop and select events. So you don't need to pass them through the moment constructor first in order to format them. You can just format the objects directly. So `moment(event.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY')` is unnecessary, you can just do `event.start.format("...` etc.

Comment: to address the time issue, it looks like maybe you're trying to get it into ISO format (which is a good idea). Have you tried simply `event.start.toISOString();`? See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/ Also if you're having issues sending data to the server, it could be an encoding issue since you're building your query parameters by manual concatenation in the ajax call. Try creating a JSON object instead and let jQuery handle the encoding for you. e.g. `data: { "title": event.title, "start": start ...` etc